# If I install Vista SP1 before I enable IIS, will I have to reinstall SP1?

Tags: windows-vista, installation, iis

I seem to recall that on XP, if you installed plain XP, upgraded to a service pack, then went into the setup program for XP and enabled IIS, it copied files from the original XP cd (location), which meant you probably had to reapply the service pack afterwards, to secure the new IIS installation.

At least, that's what I always did.

Was I wrong about that for XP, and what about Vista? Do I have to reapply SP1 after enabling IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently installed Service Pack 2 for Vista separately and compared it's binaries to the slip streamed SP2 installation and they were the same. I will therefore say no, you don't need to reapply the service pack.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected as much since "enabling IIS" sounds different from "installing IIS".